# Onesignal not sending all Android Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, onesignal

I am using onesignal for android push notifications. But not all notifications are being sent. Sometimes notifications are sent while sometimes they are not.... Whats the problem? Please Explain.

the problem is not with the code because some notification get sent but most of them do not get sent.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few more details that are needed to be able to diagnose this problem.

First, is OneSignal saying that there were any errors? If so, you can find the cause of the errors by visiting the settings page for your OneSignal app and selecting "Show details" next to any visible errors or warnings.

Next, if OneSignal is not showing 0 possible recipients then that means your device has not opted-in to notifications, or the device has uninstalled your app, or the OneSignal SDK was not properly installed in your app.

Finally, if OneSignal is showing that the notification was delivered but it was not received, the most common causes of this issue on Android devices are as follows:

1. The user has force-closed your app. (Notifications will not be delivered to apps that were force closed)
2. The user has denied notification permissions ( Check the notification setting under Settings > Apps)
3. App is closed on a Huawei or Xiaomi device due their custom Android tweaks.

   a. Huawei - Go to Settings > "Protected apps", check your app.

   b. Xiaomi - Make sure "Auto-start" property enabled for your app in the settings.
4. In app - A notification will not be displayed on the device if your app is currently in focus by default. However, you can call EnableInAppAlertNotification with true to show notifications as alert boxes in your app.